# Recuperar arreglo en javascript y enviarlo a php

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo un problema que no puedo resolver, tengo un formulario el cual contiene una seccion de inputs checkbox que se generan dinamicamente, el nombre de este input lo guardo como **mail_2[]** mi problema es como puedo recoger ese arreglo en js para enviarlo a php donde sera tratado el array?

Mi pregunta seria entonces, como enviar el arreglo de js a php?
lo intete de la siguinte manera pero al eviarlo parace que no se envia nada:

```
mail_2 = document.mailing.elements['mail_2[]'];
```

Mi input:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label>Promociones Disponibles:</label>
              <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                        <?php
                           while($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) { ?>
                               <input name="mail_2[]"  id="mail_2" class="styled" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $f[llave] ?>">
                               <label>
                                <?php echo $f[titulo] ?>    
                                </label>
                                <br>
                          <?php }
                       ?>
              </div>
             </div>
```

Esta es mi funcion completa:

```
 function mailing_envio(){

    var selectedValues = [];    
    $("#ms :selected").each(function(){
        selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    //alert(selectedValues);
    //return false;

    titulo_mail = document.mailing.titulo_mail.value;
    mail_2 = document.mailing.elements['mail_2[]'];


    ajax = objetoAjax();
    if(selectedValues=='usuarios'){
    //alert("correo para usuarios");
    ajax.open("POST", "class/mailing_enviar.php", true);
    }else if(selectedValues=='prospectos'){
    alert("correo para prospectos"+mail_2);
    //ajax.open("POST", "class/actualizar.php", true);
    }else{
     alert("correo para todos");   
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==2) {
            alert("Datos enviados)
        }
    }
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send("titulo_mail="+titulo_mail+"&mail_2="+mail_2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como todos los elementos son *checkboxes* que tienen el nombre `mail_2[]`, puedes seleccionarlos basándote en el nombre y entonces concatenar los valores de las cajas que estén marcadas.

Una posible opción para ello. En lugar de hacer esto:

```
mail_2 = document.mailing.elements['mail_2[]'];
```

Selecciona las cajas que tengan el nombre `mail_2[]` y estén marcadas, y concatena sus valores. El código sería algo como esto:

```
// array que contendrá los valores seleccionados
var valores = new Array();
// array con los checkboxes que tienen nombre mail_2[] y que están marcados
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[name='mail_2[]']:checked");
// atravesamos el array de inputs
for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    // insertando su valores en el array de valores
    valores.push(inputs[x].value);
}
// asignamos a mail_2 la concatenación de los valores
mail_2 = valores.join(",");
```

De este modo, la variable `mail_2` contendrá una cadena de texto con los valores seleccionados separados por coma, y podrías mantener el resto de código de manera similar a como está ahora.

Comment: Wo muchas gracias Alvaro, ni siquiera tuve que pensarle me lo dejaste hecho y funciona jeje. Ya van 2 que me salvas, muchas gracias :)